# How to make sequalize bulk create x number of same record with only dates incremented?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create x number of records for x number of incremental days for a simple model like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequalize, DataTypes){
var Availability = sequalize.define('availability', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    reserved: {
        type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
  });   
  return Availability;

}
```

Is there any smart bulk create method that I can use without building the object with a for loop?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the actual data to look like? This might be as simple as using `generate_series`, but it's difficult to tell from your ORM definition.

Comment: the data would be something like: 1   2016/06/01T00:00   false, 2  2016/06/02   false, 3  2016/06/03.... basically bunch of record with date increments.

Comment: why is this  tagged postgresql?

Comment: That's my db. I was thinking there might be something specific to postgresql that allows data entry with date increment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SQL directly, then there's a relatively straightforward way to do this. The `generate_series` function returns a one-column table with a series of data.

```
INSERT INTO availability
  (date)
SELECT *
  FROM generate_series('2016-06-01'::date, 
                       '2016-08-01'::date,
                       '1 day');
```

See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) for more details.

Comment: This is only supported in PostgreSQL though, so if you'd use this method you'd be stuck with PostgreSQL, which I don't find a nice solution, considering we're using an ORM, of which one of the benefits is cross-database compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation without using PostgeSQL specific functionality, using just Sequelize and JavaScript dates:

(I know, this is done with constructing objects with a for loop, but this might be interesting for other people just searching for a way to create records with different dates, without sacrificing being able to switch databases)

```
//This will create 5 dates, each with 1 day inbetween, starting from today:
var today = new Date();
var dates = [];
dates.push(today);
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //TODO: change each element of 'dates' to be an object, add the remaining 
    //attributes of 'Availability' with a date to each of this objects
    var nextDay = new Date(dates[i].getTime());
    nextDay.setDate(dates[i].getDate() + 1);
    dates.push(nextDay);
}
//'dates' will contain 5 dates now.
//TODO: handle '.then' and '.catch'
Availability.bulkCreate(dates);
```